# Elasticsearch 7 - prevent fields from being searchable

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I know I can prevent fields from being indexed by setting the [enabled mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html) to false. This does work as expected but I am concerned that some of these fields will be needed in the future.

In my use case, I am searching for a product SKU of `t-shirt-small-red` and while ES7 does return the correct results, it also returns everything else as I am indexing the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields with dates `2020-02-08 00:00:00`.

At least for now, I have no use for searching these within my app so I would like a way to exclude these from any search while keeping them indexed for future use. I am guessing I may want to perform filtering or aggregation on these in the future.

I know I can limit the search to just a single field but that does not work for this either. I need the search to work across every field apart from these 2 date fields.

Comment: You just exclude them in the fields argument of your query

Answer (score 1):

As in one of the comments, you can exclude them from the fields part of the query. I was not using fields before so it actually means specifying all the fields explicitly.

Additionally, I found that specifying the field type as date also ensures they did not show up as false positives in the search.